# Error while connecting to external SQL Server with an IP using SQL Management Studio 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms-2005

Error while connecting to external SQL Server IP using SQL Management Studio 2005 address

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to 1.2.3.4\SQLEXPRESS.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL
>   Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the
>   instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network
>   Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft
>   SQL Server, Error: -1)
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-1&LinkId=20476

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that remote server allows connection to port `1433/tcp`, e.g.:

using telnet client (in Windows 7 isn't installed by default, to install use `Turn Windows features`):

```
telnet 1.2.3.4 1433
```

or using [nmap](http://nmap.org) (port scanner)

```
nmap -sT -r -n -vv -p1433 1.2.3.4
```

If doesn't allow - check inbound firewall rules.

Answer (score 1):

By default, SQL Server 2005 doesn’t allow remote connection so you have to enable it manually. So if @abatishchev's solution doesn't get you going; it may be you haven't set the permissions to connect.

Run the Surface Area Configuration Manager (it should be in the SQL Server folder in My Programs under Configuration Tools).
Choose Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections
Select your server expand database engine and then remote connections and enable TCP/IP and / or tcp/ip and named pipes. Click Apply.

Whilst you are here check the SQL Server Browser is set to run. Expand it out and choose the service; change the startup type to be Automatic.

Try again in management studio express to connect to the machine.